# icecast online radio , how to implement playlist and broadcasting from microphone input

Tags: streaming, live-streaming, icecast

I want to implement an online radio that will live in my own server and admin will have the option to select mp3 files just as they do in a media player play list. And admin will also be able to pause the mp3 file playing and start broadcasting from the microphone input.

in order to implement that in an online Linux server -

1) which source client should I use that will be easy to fulfill my requirements ?

2) Should the mp3 files be uploaded in the server first to give the admin the ability to select it from  there or should the ability be such that the mp3 files will be selected by browsing the hard drive? Which one is better for performance ?

Comment: What platform will the admin be using?  Are you trying to make this web-based?

Comment: @Brad, php, yes web based

Comment: How will you do the audio capture?  You can either use Flash, or `getUserMedia` which is not widely supported yet.

Comment: @Brad, looking for the solution

Comment: Well, pick one of those two.  The capturing solution you pick has implications on how you build the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

just use Sam Broadcaster... its a software that is specially designed to be able to use your mic and play mp3, then send them to the icecast server, there are a couple of guides around the web, but overall its a simple program, its what i use at least, you dont need to upload anything either